# Interchanging probability and limits

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am trying to prove that $\mathbb{P}(\cup A_n)=1$ if $\mathbb{P}(\limsup A_n)=1$ when $A_1...A_n$ are independent events and $\mathbb{P}(A_n)<1$. My question is, while trying to prove this, can I interchange the limit and probability and can I do that always or are there conditions when I can't ? $\mathbb{P}(\limsup A_n)=\lim_{n \to \infty}(\mathbb{P}(\cup_{m\geq n} A_m))$ . Also if $\mathbb{P}(A_n)<1$ then why is $\sum \mathbb{P}(A_n) = \infty$ ?

Comment: If the sequence of events $\{B_n : n \geq 1\}$ satisfies $B_n \subset B_{n+1}$ for all $n$, then it is legitimate to write $\lim_n \Bbb P(B_n) = \Bbb P(\cup_n B_n)$. In all other cases, you have to find a specific argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\omega\in\limsup_n A_n$ then $\omega$ is in infinitely many $A_n$'s, in particular in one of them. Hence 
$$1=\mathbb P\left(\limsup_{n\to \infty}A_n\right)\leqslant \mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{n\geqslant 1}A_n\right)\leqslant 1.$$

For the last question, the answer follows from Borel-Cantelli's lemma.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to use the BC Lemma for such an easy statement...

Comment: Why? The converse is _exactly_ the statement of Borel-Cantelli's lemma.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. What I meant is that given the level of the question, it is probably more profitable for the OP to answer from first principles than to invoque a more general lemma. The best is when both answers are given, because they complement each other.